# Enriching serilog with context based on logEvent's LogEventLevel (not logger's minimum)

Tags: c#, serilog

I'd like to centralize the "ForContext" enrichment in my classes, like so

```
public class MyClass {
    //define all common cases with a fluent approach
    ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.Logger
        .ForConditionalContext(logEventLvl => logEventLvl <= LogEventLevel.Information, "prop 1", "appended to Information and below only")
        .ForConditionalContext(logEventLvl => logEventLvl <= LogEventLevel.Debug, "prop 2","appended to Debug and below only")
        .ForConditionalContext(logEventLvl => logEventLvl == LogEventLevel.Verbose, "prop 3", "appended to Verbose only");

    void MyMethod() {
        //this will be enriched with lots of props
        Log.ForContext("method-specific ctx", "value")
            .Verbose("this will be enriched with lots of props");
        //this will be enriched with little props
        Log.ForContext("method-specific ctx", "value")
            .Information("this will be enriched with little props");
    }
}
```

So far the only thing that came to mind is writing separate loggers, and remembering to use the appropriate one each time (which is not ideal).

```
public class MyClass {
    ILogger RootLogger;
    //switch over LogEventLevel to produce the required logger
    ILogger GetLogger(LogEventLevel lvl) {
        switch(lvl) {
            case LogEventLevel.Verbose: return RootLogger
                    .ForContext("prop 3", "appended to Verbose only");
            /* other cases */
        }
    }
    

    void MyMethod() {
        //this will be enriched with lots of props
        GetLogger(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .ForContext("method-specific ctx", "value")
            .Verbose("this will be enriched with lots of props");
        //this will be enriched with little props
        GetLogger(LogEventLevel.Information)
            .ForContext("method-specific ctx", "value")
            .Information("this will be enriched with little props");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to attain this result?
I've searched the web estensively for related documentation, but the closer i got is
 `new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.AtLevel(/*...*/)`
which requires the fluent creation of a new logger, (and only supports >=)

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer was simply using ForContext(enricher) with a custom one.
My bad.

```
/// <summary>
/// conditionally enrich the LogContext with a custom property </summary>
public class ConditionalEnricher : ILogEventEnricher {
    private Func<LogEvent, bool> condition;
    private ILogEventEnricher enricher;

    public ConditionalEnricher(Func<LogEventLevel, bool> withLevel, ILogEventEnricher enricher) : this(evt => withLevel(evt.Level), enricher) {
    }
    public ConditionalEnricher(Func<LogEvent, bool> condition, ILogEventEnricher enricher) {
        Debug.Assert(condition is not null && enricher is not null);
        this.condition = condition ?? (evt => true);
        this.enricher = enricher ?? new Serilog.Core.Enrichers.PropertyEnricher("ConditionalEnricherError", "nullEnricher");
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory) {
        if (condition(logEvent))
            enricher.Enrich(logEvent, propertyFactory);
    }
}
public static class ConditionalEnricherExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// conditionally enrich the LogContext with a custom property </summary>
    public static ILogger ForConditionalContext(this ILogger logger, Func<LogEvent, bool> condition, string propName, object? propValue, bool destructure = false)
        => logger.ForContext(new ConditionalEnricher(condition, new Serilog.Core.Enrichers.PropertyEnricher(propName, propValue, destructure)));
    /// <summary>
    /// enrich the LogContext with a custom property only when </summary>
    public static ILogger ForConditionalContext(this ILogger logger, Func<LogEventLevel, bool> hasLogLevelOf, string propName, object? propValue, bool destructure = false)
        => logger.ForContext(new ConditionalEnricher(hasLogLevelOf, new Serilog.Core.Enrichers.PropertyEnricher(propName, propValue, destructure)));
    
}
```